# Laravel composer update

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Sir, I am new in Laravel, I am making a form to insert the values in database. I wanna ask that do I need to update the composer every time whenever I want to use Form ? or There is no need to update the **composer** every time ?

Comment: I think you should read https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md to find out what composer is

Comment: No, there is no need to update composer or the project dependencies *every* time.

Answer (score 0):

No. You only need to update composer when you add new PHP plugin or need to update existing plugin. E.g. Upgrading Laravel version or installing MongoDB or update from 2.3 to 5.2 version. In those case you only require to execute `composer update` otherwise not.

Good Luck!

Comment: In your example one would probably use an upgrade not an update. If your composer versions allow such an upgrade there might be something wrong with your understanding of versioning.

Comment: I just wanted to share a brief. Surely we need upgrade for versioning. But in case of collaboration we get change in composer.json file and for that composer update works for versioning.

Answer (score 0):

Might you installed laravel/installer globally via

> composer global update laravel/installer

Run this command to update the composer and your composer will work fine.

> composer update --no-scripts

Answer (score 0):

No, the composer doesn't need to be updated every single time you want to use the form.